# Ant: How to echo the name of targetfile within apply

Tags: ant, echo, task, apply

I'm not really familiar with Ant and i wonder how to print the name of the current processed file to the commandline.

This is what i have so far... It's a part of a macro which minifys files with the yui-compressor.

```
<apply executable="java" parallel="false" verbose="true" dest="@{target}">

    <fileset dir="@{src}">
        <include name="**/*.@{filetype}"/>
    </fileset>

    <arg line="-jar" />
    <arg path="${yui.jar}" />
    <arg value="--charset" />
    <arg value="ANSI" />
    <arg value="-o" />
    <targetfile />

    <mapper type="glob" from="*.@{filetype}" to="*.min.@{filetype}" />
</apply>
```

What i'm trying to get:

```
 [echo] Start!
[apply] Processed: filename-1.min.js
[apply] Processed: filename-2.min.js
[apply] Processed: filename-3.min.js
 [echo] Success!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a lot of experience with apply but you could try defining your fileset out of the apply element , getting your printed results and then referring to it into your apply element.

```
<fileset dir="@{src}" id="my.files">
    <include name="**/*.@{filetype}"/>
</fileset>
<pathconvert pathsep="${line.separator}" property="processed.files" refid="my.files"/>
<echo>Start!</echo>
<echo message="${processed.files}"/>

<apply executable="java" parallel="false" verbose="true" dest="@{target}">
    <fileset refid="my.files"/>
    <arg line="-jar" />
    <arg path="${yui.jar}" />
    <arg value="--charset" />
    <arg value="ANSI" />
    <arg value="-o" />
    <targetfile />

    <mapper type="glob" from="*.@{filetype}" to="*.min.@{filetype}" />
</apply>

<echo>Success!</echo>
```

Of course this will only work if the apply executable doesn't print anything to clutter the output.

Comment: Note: this will print *all* file names *before* starting apply rather than 'current processed file' that OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to do this is to add the debug or verbose flag to ant:

`ant target-name -debug` or `ant target-name -verbose`

This will then print the executing command-line. For example:

```
[apply] Executing 'lib\NUnit\bin\nunit-console-x86.exe' with arguments:
[apply] '/noshadow'
[apply] '/domain:multiple'
[apply] '/labels'
[apply] '/framework:net-4.5'
[apply] '/nologo'
[apply] 'C:\blah\foo.Tests.dll
```

Unfortunately, this will verbosely log everything, and not just the specific `apply`.